# Async support in Web Pages 2.0

Tags: webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

Are asynchronous (either async/await or TPL) operations supported in Web Pages 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

async/await syntax should work fine with Web Pages 2.0 in Visual Studio, as long as you're targeting .NET 4.5.  However, WebMatrix does not currently support C# 5.0 or .NET 4.5.